# Python equivalent of Ruby's .find

Tags: python, ruby, language-comparisons

I'm trying to implement the following Ruby method into a Python Method:

```rb
CF = {:metre=>{:kilometre=>0.001, :metre=>1.0, :centimetre=>100.0}, :litre=>{:litre=>1.0, :millilitre=>1000.0, :imperial_pint=>1.75975}}

def common_dimension(from, to)
  CF.keys.find do |canonical_unit|
    CF[canonical_unit].keys.include?(from) &&
    CF[canonical_unit].keys.include?(to)
  end
end
```

Which behaves like:

```
>> common_dimension(:metre, :centimetre)
=> :metre

>> common_dimension(:litre, :centimetre)
=> nil

>> common_dimension(:millilitre, :imperial_pint)
=> :litre
```

What is the "Pythonic" way to implement this?

Comment: A quick tip when checking if a key is present in a hash Ruby. Use [`#key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) or [`#has_key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) instead. This is shorter and quicker due to the fact that it uses key lookup instead of looping though all keys to test if one of the keys is equal to the given key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code in python for your ruby logic.

```
CF={"metre":{"kilometre":0.001, "metre":1.0, "centimetre":100.0}, "litre":{"litre":1.0, "millilitre":1000.0, "imperial_pint":1.75975}}

def common(fr,to):
    for key,value in CF.items():
        if (fr in value) and (to in value):
            return key   

print(common('metre','centimdetre'))
metre
print(com('metre','centimdetre'))
None
******************

single line function 
com = lambda x,y:[key for key,value in CF.items() if (x in value) and (y in value)]
print(com('metre','centimdetre'))
['metre']
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option both for Ruby and Python.

For Ruby:

```
cf = {:metre=>{:kilometre=>0.001, :metre=>1.0, :centimetre=>100.0}, :litre=>{:litre=>1.0, :millilitre=>1000.0, :imperial_pint=>1.75975}}

from = :litre
to = :millilitre
cf.select { |k, v| ([from, to] - v.keys).empty? }.keys
#=> [:litre]
```

For Python:

```
CF = {'metre': {'kilometre': 0.001, 'metre': 1.0, 'centimetre': 100.0}, 'litre': {'litre': 1.0, 'millilitre': 1000.0, 'imperial_pint': 1.75975}}

_from = 'millilitre'
_to = 'imperial_pint'
res = [ k for k, v in CF.items() if not bool(set([_from, _to]) - set(v.keys())) ]
#=> ['litre']
```

Comment: Hi iGian, I am surprised you know Python as well. May I know which language is more easy according to you? Or more easy to use?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Off topic as too broad! :) Hard to tell. I'm not a pro, just having fun in learning. They are similar. I like more Ruby syntax. Python has powerful libraries, see SciPy. I'd suggest: try it yourself.